# ¿Por qué un teléfono móvil o celular es un "celulitis" en Honduras?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, honduras

A raíz de la pregunta [Is using Spanish from Latin America and The Caribbean (es-419) in a website appropriate to show outisde that area?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19344/1674) encontré una lista muy interesante en la Wikipedia en español: [Apéndice:Palabras no de jerga del español que pueden causar malentendidos](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ndice:Palabras_no_de_jerga_del_espa%C3%B1ol_que_pueden_causar_malentendidos).

Allí estoy pasando un muy buen rato descubriendo (o más bien confirmando) qué tan diferentes acepciones puede tener una misma palabra, con el agravante de tener connotaciones "peligrosas" según el país en el que se usen.

Me ha hecho particular gracia la siguiente:

> [**celulitis**](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/celulitis)
>   - inflamación del tejido celular subcutáneo por exceso de adiposidad (en todos los países) [en género femenino]
>   - teléfono celular (en Honduras) [en género masculino]

El Diccionario de americanismos no la recoge, pero encuentro una referfencia en [tuBabel](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/15403-celulitis):

> vulgarmente se dice celulitis al teléfono celular o portátil.
>   Te está sonando el celulitis

¿Alguien sabe por qué en Honduras, y solo allí, *celulitis* tiene esta acepción?

Comment: [En Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Honduras/comments/5oae28/por_qu%C3%A9_un_tel%C3%A9fono_celular_es_un_celulitis_en/) alguien lo reconoció: _simplemente por el parecido de la palabra, celular... celulitis_. He preguntado por su popularidad, pues las dos respuestas sugieren que no lo es demasiado. Añado: me indican que es común en Tegucigalpa, no en otros lugares.

Comment: Jeje parece que esta pregunta es candidato a guillotina. Los Hondureños niegan que se usa y tu link a wikitionary no hace ninguna referencia a tal definición (https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/celulitis) Solo la tal lista esa lo contenía.

Comment: @DGaleano voy tirando del hilo y algo sale: [Celulitis se vuelve viral](http://www.elheraldo.hn/vida/815985-220/celulitis-se-vuelve-viral) y [Banton muestra la 'Celulitis' de su novia en video](http://www.nacion.com/ocio/musica/Banton-muestra-emCelulitisem-novia-video_0_1469053092.html). En la canción, este cantante hondureño habla de la _celulitis_ como la adicción al celular de su novia. Por tanto, la palabra no sería sinónima de teléfono móvil sino una manera de denominar la "enfermedad" de estar enganchado.

Comment: Soy de México, lo he escuchado talvez 2 ocasiones, refiriéndose a una enfermedad (**inventada**) asociada a la dependencia del celular, quizá por algo muy común del mexicano, agregar el [itis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itis) para inventar enfermedades. Por ejemplo: [Huevon-itis](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/Index.php?pais=M%E9xico&palabra=huevonitis&tipobusqueda=1)

Comment: @jasilva ¡gracias! Coincide con lo que había comentado un poco más arriba, y por lo que comentas no es típico solamente de Honduras. Al fin y al cabo, pues, esto no es un sinónimo de _celular_ sino una mera construcción para hablar de la adicción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soy de México, lo he escuchado muy pocas ocasiones, siempre refiriéndose a una enfermedad (inventada) asociada a la dependencia del celular.

Por ejemplo:

> Ya deja eso (refiriéndose al celular), parece que tienes **celulitis**

o

> -¿Ya hiciste tu tarea?
>
> -No
>
> -¿Como que no? Otra vez con tu **celulitis**!
>
> <sub>El interlocutor no ha hecho su tarea por estar con el celular</sub>

Algo muy común del mexicano, es agregar el itis para inventar enfermedades. Por ejemplo: [Huevon-itis](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/Index.php?pais=M%E9xico&palabra=huevonitis&tipobusqueda=1)

Answer (score 4):

Yo soy de la zona central de Honduras, Tegucigalpa y celulitis no es una palabra utilizada para un teléfono celular, por el contrario, el único uso es el primero indicado, sobre el tejido adiposo excedente en el cuerpo.

Answer (score 3):

Nací en Tegucigalapa y he vivido (por mas de un año) en las siguientes ciudades hondureñas: Comayagua, Tegucigalapa, Nacaome, Catacamas, y Tela. Jamás he escuchado a alguien referirse al celular como "celulitis".